# How to redirect the stdout of a multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, stringio, redirectstandardoutput

I'm using Python 3.7.4 and I have created two functions, the first one executes a callable using **multiprocessing.Process** and the second one just prints "Hello World". Everything seems to work fine until I try redirecting the stdout, doing so prevents me from getting any printed values during the process execution. I have simplified the example to the maximum and this is the current code I have of the problem.

**These are my functions:**

```py
import io
import multiprocessing
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


def call_function(func: callable):
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()                                      
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda:queue.put(func()))
    process.start()          

    while True:
        if not queue.empty():
            return queue.get()


def print_hello_world():
    print("Hello World")
```

**This works:**

```py
call_function(print_hello_world)
```

The previous code works and successfully prints "Hello World"

**This does not work:**

```py
with redirect_stdout(io.StringIO()) as out:
    call_function(print_hello_world)
print(out.getvalue())
```

With the previous code I do not get anything printed in the console.

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated. I have been able to narrow the problem to this point and I think is related to the process ending after the io.StringIO() is already closed but I have no idea how to test my hypothesis and even less how to implement a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the workaround I found. It seems that if I use a file instead of a StringIO object I can get the things to work.

```py
with open("./tmp_stdout.txt", "w") as tmp_stdout_file:
    with redirect_stdout(tmp_stdout_file):
        call_function(print_hello_world)
    stdout_str = ""
    for line in tmp_stdout_file.readlines():
        stdout_str += line
    stdout_str = stdout_str.strip()

print(stdout_str)  # This variable will have the captured stdout of the process
```

Another thing that might be important to know is that the multiprocessing library buffers the stdout, meaning that the prints only get displayed after the function has executed/failed, to solve this you can force the stdout to flush when needed within the function that is being called, in this case, would be inside **print_hello_world** (I actually had to do this for a daemon process that needed to be terminated if it ran for more than a specified time)

```py
sys.stdout.flush()  # This will force the stdout to be printed
```